# Eloquent relations

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Im having a bit of trouble to find the best and correct way to set up my Models relationships to fetch some of my data below...

my plan is to display **content** depending on the **content_type** and the link between is the **id** from the Users table and the **user_id** form UserData table. Those are both models too **Users** and **UserData**

**Users table**

```
*id*    *username*  *password* 
1       johndoe     123
2       janedoe     321
```

**UserData table**

```
*user_id    *content*         *content_type*
1           John Doe          full_name
1           john-doe.jpg      avatar
1           laravel           twitter
1           blue              favorite_color
2           Jane Doe          full_name
2           jane-doe.jpg      avatar
2           Eloquent          twitter
2           green             favorite_color
```

I hope someone can see what my purpose here is and know a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up two relations in your User model:

```
public function data() {
    return $this->hasMany('UserData');
}

public function dataOfType($type) {
    return $this->hasOne('UserData')->where('content_type', $type);
}
```

Then you can either get all the data associated with a particular user (user 1, in this case) with

```
$userData = User::find(1)->data;
```

Or, you can specify a particular content_type to retrieve:

```
$userData = User::find(1)->dataOfType('avatar')->content;
```

To get all the users, along with their associated data:

```
$users = User::with('data')->get();
```

You can't use the `dataOfType` relation for eager loading, since the `with` statement doesn't accept parameters (which you need in order to specify the content_type). If you need to do this for more than one user and want to use eager loading—so, for instance, you want to get all users with their avatars—you could use an eager loading constraint rather than your `dataOfType` relation.

```
$users = User::with(array('data' => function($query)
{
    $query->where('content_type', 'avatar');
}))->get();
```

---

For example, for a particular user, to get their `full_name` value, you would run:

```
$userFullName = User::find(1)->dataOfType('full_name')->content;
```

Or, to get all users with their `full_name` values:

```
$users = User::with(array('data' => function($query)
    { $query->where('content_type', 'full_name'); }
))->get();
```

...and the value for each user would be accessible (within a `foreach ($users as $user)` loop) at `$user->content`.

Answer (score 0):

From what i see, you are trying to have dynamic data for users right?

If so, you will have two options:

1) make use of Polymorphic Relationships, where you will have a class for each content_type, and when fetching, it will convert it to the class, and then inside the class, you can override the __toString method to display as you want it. 
You can find more about Polymorphic Relationships here: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#polymorphic-relations

2) you could add another column which will say how to present it, and treat the different content_type manually everytime when printing, or adding methods to your model to return them as you want.

Now, about the relationship between UserData and User, you will have a OneToMany relation, so, you wil have in User model:

```
public function data(){
     return $this->hasMany("UserData");
}
```

And in UserData model:

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo("User");
}
```

Comment: i set up the relations now. how do i get *content* where *content_type* is full_name?

Comment: I cant get the Polymorphic-relations to work.. Do you mind showing an example?